# Python IRC bot weird output

Tags: python, irc

I have written a code that pms and notices specified nickname:

```
 @hook.command
    def privatemsg(inp,nick="",conn=None):
        conn.cmd('PRIVMSG',[inp,''])
    @hook.command
    def notice(inp,nick="",conn=None):
        conn.cmd('NOTICE',[inp,''])
```

But the problem shows up when I do .notice Tom hi, it outputs something like -Bot- hi**:**
Same happens with .privatemsg Tom hi, outputs -Bot- hi:

How can I remove the **:**? I've tried changing the '' but it still shows :

Comment: Could you provide some more details on which irc library you are using? Shouldn't the nickname be somewhere in the command you are sending?

Comment: @jone my bot is based on SkyBot. https://github.com/rmmh/skybot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the correct syntax for notices is

```
conn.cmd('NOTICE', [nick, msg])
```

but there is already a built-in function in skybot for doing this.
Take a look at the [tell plugin](https://github.com/rmmh/skybot/blob/master/plugins/tell.py#L59) how it is used (which may already implement what you are trying to do?).

Comment: I tried what you said, but it notices me, because 'nick' is the one that gives the command to the bot :(

Comment: If you split the `inp` into nick and message it should work. Something like `nick, msg = inp.split(' ', 1)` (some lowercasing or stripping may be necessare). You can then remove the `nick` argument from your function definition.